На wordpress сайте перестали открываться любые страницы, кроме главной
подскажите, пожалуйста, из-за чего могут не открываться категории товаров на сайте? похоже, что-то сломалось в постоянных ссылках.
сейчас настройки такие:

и, пытаясь открыть категории на сайте, вижу следующее:


Если зайти в раздел постоянных ссылок, и поменять ссылки категорий на что-то другое (например, category-0 вместо просто category), то все начинает работать по новому адресу.

Но стоит только вернуть на старую систему, все опять ломается:

Проверял разрешения htaccess - стоит 644. Пробовал удалять его и создавать заново - не помогло.

Измени слаг базы категорий товара.

И нигде, никогда не используй зарезервированные термины

Есть ли возможность сохранить именно этот слаг? он уже в вебмастере и обходится роботом давно, все было хорошо до этого момента

@Den сделай редирект с этих страниц, так будет лучше и правильнее. А все манипуляции со слагами и пермалинками рано или поздно приводят к проблемам. И да, ещё рекомендую грамотно оформить 404 страницу чтобы не терять пользователя.


вероятно нужно просто нажать кнопку
Настройки -> Настройки постоянных ссылок -> Сохранить изменения
и попробуйте перейти на страницу

если у вас мультисайт то проблема может быть в nginx, в файле  .htaccess в корневой папке сайта должны быть добавлены следующие строки:




define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false );
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'your_domain_name' );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );



